# selenium - "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000" while making a screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

when running cucumber scenarios on Jenkins, sometimes encounter this error: "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000". Because of this error, **images, screenshots are not generated** at all, How to solve this problem?

05:51:16 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

05:51:16   (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

05:51:16 Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'

05:51:16 System info: host: '192-168-1-44', ip: '192.168.1.44', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_221'

Comment: First of all, make sure you are using correct version of chromedriver.

Comment: @pburgr  it is the last version of availiable chrome driver, that was updated approximately 2 months ago, this error starting coming up just recently, 2-3 weeks ago

Comment: increase the implicit wait. If the error persists add your code sample.

Answer (score -1):

Comment this line in your code or  increase the timeout seconds.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(seconds,10);
```